# Where do you set the class path in a cordova cli plugin build

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I am putting together an android plugin for cordova using the cli that uses a third party aar and am getting symbol does not exist errors.

As best that I can work out it is because cordova's build needs to be told that there is an an aar in libs. It needs to be included on the classpath.

Normally any configuration changes required by a plugin would be made in plugin.xml. Does anyone know what I need to set to tell cordova about the aar.

(I have checked and the aar is actually in project/libs as a result of the plugin line)

```
<source-file src="libs/android/mopub-sdk.aar" target-dir="libs" />
```

or is my problem a little deeper and its not a plugin.xml problem - its something I need to configure in cordova  cli?

Comment: did you find out a solution?

Comment: yep @dbaq, check it out my answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have a similar problem. What works for me was adding this .aar to a folder named 'aars' inside the root/platforms/android folder. And also creating the  build-extras.gradle file (you have to create this file on the root/platforms/android folder) with the following code:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
android {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'io.filepicker:filepicker-android:3.8.14@aar'// IN YOUR CASE, PUT THE CORRECT NAME THAT MATCHS YOURS AAR
}
}
```

Now, when it compiles, it gets the .aar and set up in the build path.
If yours aar uses a thrid library, you should include (copy/paste to  libs) folder. You have to make this to include those libraries on the build-path so it will be on the .apk when you generated.
Now, you just need to import the /platforms/android folder in the eclipse, and then click with the right button on the project>properties>JAva build path>order and export. Now you just need to check Android private libraries and you're good to go.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If you need to remove the android platform for any matters, you have to do this steps again. I really dont know if there is a script or a nicer way to do this.